# LWC Download folder as zip from Google Drive

Tags: lightning-web-components, js, zip

I have a problem with download files from Google Drive with Salesforce. I compress files in zip and download its.

I get filecontent with this api method:

```
public String getFileContent(String fileId){
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setEndpoint(baseEndpoint + 'files/' + fileId + '?alt=media&' + generateOptionalParameters());
    System.debug('Endpoint: ' + request.getMethod() + '__' + request.getEndpoint());
    HttpResponse response = new http().send(request); 
    System.debug('Response ' + response.getBody());
    System.debug('Content-Type: ' + response.getHeader('Content-Type'));
    String body = response.getBody();
    return body;
}
```

Everything is ok, folder downloaded, but files (pdf, png, jpeg...) don't open. I use this script:

```
async downloadFolder(folder) {
const zip = new JSZip();

async function createZipArchive(zipFolder, folderId) {
    const folderContent = await getFolderContent({ folderId });
    const files = folderContent.files;

    for (const file of files) {
        if (file.mimeType.includes("folder")) {
            const innerFolder = zipFolder.folder(file.name);
            await createZipArchive(innerFolder, file.id);
        } else {
            console.log(file.mimeType);
            const fileContent = await getFileContent({ fileId: file.id });
            
            const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
            const encodedContent = textEncoder.encode(fileContent);


            const blob = new Blob([encodedContent], { type: file.mimeType });
            zipFolder.file(file.name, blob);
        }
    }
}

const rootFolder = zip.folder(folder.name);
await createZipArchive(rootFolder, folder.id);

const content = await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(content);

const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = blobUrl;
a.download = folder.name + '.zip';
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
```

}

[image]